# disable auto-commit in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm a student

I'm trying to disable the auto-commit feature in oracle so I can successfully manage savepoints and rollbacks

there is no auto-commit button in the interface I'm using, do you know how to disable it?

[image]

**Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 2):

- connect to the internal workspace as admin user
- go to "Manage instance" menu (at the top of the screen), then

  - Feature configuration

    - SQL Workshop

      - Set "Enable transactional SQL Commands" to **Yes**
- log off, log on (as a *normal* user)
- go to SQL Workshop

  - in upper left corner of the screen, you'll now notice the **Autocommit** checkbox - uncheck it

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a hosted instance like apex.oracle.com the autocommit feature will be turned off and you can't switch it on. However, you can still test/use savepoints and rollbacks - just make sure you test them within a single anonymous pl/sql block.