# Using savepoint, commit and rollback in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I used to work with SQL*Plus tool and I used savepoints and rollbacks in my work. Now Im using oracle apex and when I try to use a savepoint the system shows me this error:

[image]
am I doing something wrong? or the system does not support these commands anymore? if yes, is there any alternative with the same function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069245/disable-auto-commit-in-oracle-apex

Comment: thank you but from where I can access the "Feature configuration" please? could you please reply me with pictures?

Comment: This is configured at instance level, not at workspace level. It is explained in that referenced question how to set this. It could be that you don't have permissions to do this. Is this on your own local install or on a hosted instance like apex.oracle.com ?

Comment: I'm not working with any local installed software, I'm working with the apex.oracle.com website, is that a hosted instance? I’m new to apex so thats why I don't have much information.

Comment: Yes that is hosted - that instance administration is done by oracle. For large scale instances like that one, autocommit is turned on

Comment: So that means I can not turn it off or I can not use theses command (savepoint, rollback, commit) as long as Im using the hosted instance?

Comment: Did you read my answer in the referenced question ? I think that exactly answers your question.

Comment: I did, you said: “ However, you can still test/use savepoints and rollbacks - just make sure you test them within a single anonymous pl/sql block.“  but it shows me an error, could you please show me the structure of the query for savepoint and rollback?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to use COMMIT/ROLLBACK/SAVEPOINT in an anonymous pl/sql block. This can be done in SQL Workshop in apex.

1. Create helper table

```
create table commits_test (col1 VARCHAR2(10));
```

2. Create helper function to return rowcount of helper table

```
create or replace function commits_test_rows RETURN NUMBER
AS
  l_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_rows FROM commits_test;
  RETURN l_rows;
END commits_test_rows;
/
```

3. Code to show COMMIT/ROLLBACK and SAVEPOINT.

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM commits_test;
  INSERT INTO commits_test (col1) VALUES ('FIRST');
  COMMIT;
  dbms_output.put_line('after first: '||commits_test_rows());
  INSERT INTO commits_test (col1) VALUES ('SECOND');
  ROLLBACK;
  dbms_output.put_line('after second: '||commits_test_rows());
  INSERT INTO commits_test (col1) VALUES ('THIRD');
  SAVEPOINT third;
  dbms_output.put_line('after third: '||commits_test_rows());
  INSERT INTO commits_test (col1) VALUES ('FOURTH');
  dbms_output.put_line('after fourth: '||commits_test_rows());
  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT third;
  dbms_output.put_line('after ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT third: '||commits_test_rows());
END;
/
```